# Did LEGO recently change Millennium Falcon with a smaller kit?

Tags: star-wars, sets

I have been interested in a Millennium Falcon kit but was holding back because of the price.(It was about €500) This was about two years ago.

Recently I saw another, cheaper Falcon for about €150, but I think this is a different, smaller kit, and unfortunately the only available Falcon.

Did LEGO really swap the Falcon kit for a smaller, cheaper version?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Millennium Falcon has been so popular there appears there are six known sets, and seven versions. Four of which share the exact same product name.

[Millennium Falcon, 2000 (7190)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/7190-1) 600+ pieces

[Millennium Falcon, 2003 (4488)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/4488-1) Microscale version with only 87 pieces.

[Millennium Falcon, 2004 (4504)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/4504-1) 900+ pieces (New minifigures with the flesh skin colour).

[Ultimate Collector's Millennium Falcon, 2007 (10179)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/10179-1) 5000+ pieces

[Midi-scale Millennium Falcon, 2009 (7778)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/7778-1) 2nd microscale MF with 4x more parts then the 2003 model.

[Millennium Falcon, 2011 (7965)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/7965-1) 1200+ pieces

[Millennium Falcon, Advent Calendar Day 21, 2011 (7958)](http://www.brickset.com/sets/7958-1) 13 pieces

There also appears to be some Minifig variation, R2D2 and Darth Vader only appear once on the 2000 and 2011 sets respectively.

Comment: The scary thing is, I have the first three on that list ;) Had small children when the UC version came out, so couldn't justify it :( And the 2011 one's close enough to the 2004 one that I can't really drum up the enthusiasm. Don't get me started on Slave I's though ;)

Comment: There is also a Millennium Falcon in the Star Wars advent calendar.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what is the difference between 4504 (2004) and 7965 (2011)?

Comment: @abatishchev: A large difference in style, parts and overall price.  The minifigs are also more complex/detailed

Comment: @abatishchev: The outside designs are similar, but 7965 is about 30% larger and that space is used to have more "happening" on the inside. As Ambo100 said, the minifigs are also more detailed in 7965.